# Uniform and pointwise convergence of $ f_n(x)= \begin{cases} 0,\ x\leq n \\ x-n, \ x\geq n \end{cases} $ and $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I need help with this problem:

> For the next sequence {$f_n$}, determine the pointwise limit of {$f_n$} on the interval and indicate if {$f_n$} converges uniformly to that function.

1. $
   f_n(x)=
   \begin{cases}
   0,\ x\leq n \\
   x-n, \ x\geq n
   \end{cases}
   $ on $[a,b]$ and on $\mathbb{R}$
2. $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}$ on $[0,1]$

For the first one I know that when $x\geq n$, {$f_n$} would be the identity function displaced $n$. I don't know how to take the pointwise limit of the function. How do I find the pointwise limit and how do I determine if it converges uniformly?

For the secon one I did the following: $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n-x^{2n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} x^n - \lim_{n\to\infty} x^{2n} = 0$, so the pointwise limit is $0=f(x)$ I don't know how to determine if it converges uniformly, how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yes you're right, I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that convergence to zero is not uniform on $[0,1]$ by finding the point of max of $f_n$ ($x_{max}=1/\sqrt[n]{2}$) and then proving that $f_n(x_{max})$ does not approach zero. 
$$
|f_n(x_{max})-0|=f_n(2^{-1/n})=1/4.
$$

Comment: I noticed I did not answer your first question. There, the convergence is uniform because for $n>b$, $f_n$ is identically zero. It is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$ since you always have values where, say, $f_n(x)=1$.

Comment: Oh, so I can use the max point of $f_n$ to determine uniform convergence? When should I use this method?

Comment: Yes. Proving uniform convergence for continuous functions is proving that $\max_{[a,b]} |f_n(x)-f|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ (where $f$ is the limit function). This follows from the very definition of uniform convergence on an interval. For continuous functions the supremum is just the global maximum on the interval.

Comment: Ok, thanks! When I can use this?

Comment: Whenever you are dealing with continuous functions on some closed interval. If also differentiable you can use the derivative to identify the critical points and global extrema.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, $$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,\ x\leq n \\
x-n, \ x\geq n
\end{cases}$$

the pointwise limit is $f(x) = 0$. To see this, take $x$, then for large enough $n$, $x \leq n$ and therefore  $f_n(x) = 0.$ Now, for uniform convergence, if we go back to the definition, we need to show that:
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N, \forall n \geq N, \forall x \in [a,b], f_n(x) < \epsilon.$$
This holds for $N \geq b$ (assuming $b >0$ for simplicity). Now, uniform convergence does not hold on $R$. Consider for example $x_n = n+1$, then $f_n(x_n) = 1.$

Comment: Why did you write $N\geq b$? Is it because n can't be bigger than b on that interval? Can you please explain the last part a bit more?

Comment: $x$ is bounded above by $b$, so by choosing $N \geq b$, this guarantees that $n \geq N \geq b \geq x$, and by definition of $f_n$, we will have $\forall x \in [a,b], f_n(x) = 0 \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can yo explain a little more the convergence on $R$?

Comment: That will also answer your question below. Essentially, if you had uniform convergence, then if $x_n$ converges towards $x$, we would expect $f_n(x_n) $ to converge towards $f(x)$. In other words, to disprove uniform convergence, we only need to exhibit one such sequence, as done here, and below

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.